# How come sortable area freezes if a 'remove' event is triggered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-events

**Edit**: jQuery-ui [has been modified](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/736). This question is now obsolete.

If I trigger a `'remove'` custom event on an element of a sortable area, the sortable functionality stops.

I use this `'remove'` custom event in my app to communicate between different listeners and binders and I'd like to understand why it interferes with `jquery-ui`.

I can't find documentation about the `'remove'` event anywhere. Note: there is the `remove` attribute in the options, which corresponds to the `'sortremove'` event type according to the docs, but nothing about the event type `'remove'`.

I'll have to rename my event to avoid this conflict, but is this a feature? A bug? Is the `'remove'` event used internally only, and if so, should I request that they namespace it, say `'ui-remove'`?

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yWg8v/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove` is bound when widget is created in the widget source in `_createWidget`:

```
this.element.bind( "remove." + this.widgetName, function() {
    self.destroy();
});
```

`sortable` is a widget. You will have to rename your event. Your suggestion of adding a `ui-` prefix sounds like a great solution but I am not sure how the developers would feel and how it would affect other widgets.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Sorry for the misunderstanding. Added to answer.

Comment: Ah, indeed. So it is a bug, jQuery-ui uses this internally with `triggerHandler`, but it shouldn't do anything if it's an event bubbling up. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/736

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer, keeping only the good part :-)